# SQL Foreign Key Error using Hibernate POJOs

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate

We have the following situation:
We use Java's Hibernate to write POJO-Classes to a database.
The classes are annotated as follow:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dbo.SaveEvents")
```

We get the following error when writing to the database (Table: `dbo.CodeDocuments`)

```
WARN: SQL Error: 547, SQLState: 23000
Feb 06, 2017 2:06:42 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_SaveEvents_CodeDocuments". The conflict occurred in database "OSBLEPlus_eclipse", table "dbo.CodeDocuments", column 'Id'.
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112)
```

We tried to satisfy the Foreign Key constraint by adding:
`@SecondaryTable(name = "dbo.CodeDocuments")`
But this doesn’t solve our problem. We also didn’t find a lot about how to use the `SecondaryTable` annotation properly. The mapping FK <-> PK is as follows:

```
CodeDocuments.sql:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CodeDocuments] (
    [Id]    INT         IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [FileName] VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Content]  VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_CodeDocuments_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

SaveEvents.sql:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SaveEvents] (
    [Id]        INT         IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [EventLogId]   INT          NOT NULL,
    [EventDate] DATETIME    NOT NULL,
    [SolutionName] VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [DocumentId]   INT          NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_SaveEvents] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_SaveEvents_EventLogs] FOREIGN KEY ([EventLogId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[EventLogs] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_SaveEvents_CodeDocuments] FOREIGN KEY ([DocumentId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[CodeDocuments] ([Id])
);
```

How would one go about inserting into 2 tables at once using Hibernate POJOs aka fixing the foreign key error?

Comment: You should post the full mappings of the two entities you're trying to insert together that have some type of FK <-> PK relationship.

Comment: Posted the full mappings of the two entities (the sql code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to make sure you persist your `CodeDocument` entity first folllowed by the associated `SaveEvents` entities:

```
CodeDocument codeDocument = new CodeDocument();
// set the values 
session.save( codeDocument );

SaveEvents saveEvents = new SaveEvents();
// set the values
saveEvents.setDocument( codeDocument );
session.save( saveEvents );
```

Hope that helps.